# fopen returns always NULL when i use a char array for the file name but everything works fine if i use a name like "file.txt"

Tags: c, file

```
int save(int *file,int K)
{

    int i;
    char *name;
    FILE *fp;

    name=(char *)malloc(256);


    puts("type file name\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(name,256,stdin);



    if((fp=fopen(name,"w"))==NULL)
    {
        puts("file can't be opened\n");
        return 0;
    } 

    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",K);    

    for(i=0; i<K; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",*(file+i));
    }


    fclose(fp);

    return 1;

}
```

why doesn't this work but when i use `fopen("text.txt","w")` everything works fine? How can I fix this?

Comment: In addition to what others have said, the unnecessary call to `getchar` will eat up the first character of your file name.

Comment: it s not unnecessary it will get rid of the \n from the previous scanf which is out of this function.thanks though

Comment: Then it shouldn't be part of _this_ function. In my opinion, `fscanf` and `fgets` don't mix well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `fgets` appends the newline character `'\n'` to the string. You need to trim this off first.

```
if (isspace(name[strlen(name)-1]))
   name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Print `name` and check if it's actually the same.

My guess: it contains a newline character.

If it is the case, you can remove it by replacing it with `\0`:

```
name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
```

Comment: Most probably, since `fgets()` reads the `num-1` characters or until next newline, whichever comes first.